# How can I make sure files in a Storage Bucket are being served gzipped on my website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gzip, gatsby, google-cloud-build

I have a setup like this in Google Cloud Platform for my website, a Gatsbyjs project:

1. Push to repository
2. Trigger CloudBuild that builds my Gatsby website into public folder
3. Copy the files within the "public" folder to a Storage Bucket, using rsync

However, when I visit my site (LoadBalancer connected to the Bucket), the .js,.css, .html files are not being served as gzip.
I know there seems to be a flag on `cp` command for gzip, but how does this work for `rsync`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "compress on the fly" your files with rsync this is not possible.

However, if you just want to apply to gzip transport encoding to certain files you can use the -j <...> option of [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync). This will saves network bandwidth but is going to leave the data uncompressed in the Storage bucket.

However, if you want to take uncompressed files from the public folder and send them to a bucket and keep them compressed you will need to do a `gsutil cp -z` [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp). This will compress your file (if they are not compressed in your public folder) and store them compressed in the bucket

Comment: But what do you mean by "keep"? I want the generated files to be uploaded to my bucket and served as gzip. When would I need to run it in reverse?

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if I'm clearer now!

Comment: Thanks, I found out this too, and it is working great!